# Decryption unsuccessful after enabling a PIN lock when full disk encryption is already activated

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption

I have a Moto G3 with full disk-encryption enabled when I created a PIN lock and after that when my phone was restarted I got the decryption unsuccessful message and I couldn't boot it anymore.

I would like to recover my data.

I've obtained another identical phone and have been able to isolate the bug to cryptd configuration where it is not changed from default to PIN:

10-14 16:57:02.169  6084  6103 D CryptdConnector: SND -> {14 cryptfs getpwtype}
10-14 16:57:02.170  6084  7357 D CryptdConnector: RCV <- {213 14 default}

Since my device have the bootloader locked, do I have any chance to obtain a image of the device flash, or have a shell access during the boot process so that I can decrypt with the correct PIN configuration and not with the "default" password?

Thanks!